# Javascript not working in <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with a new MVC4 site I'm working on.  I can't seem to get the javascript  to run at all.  It doesn't throw an error, it just does nothing.

What am I missing?

Here's my page code:

```
   @model IEnumerable<WiseGalleriesEntities.Medium>

   @{
         ViewBag.Title = "ManageMedium";
   }

   <div class="title">
       <h1>Mediums...</h1>
   </div>

   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Medium", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId =    "MediumListDiv" }, new { id = "frmAddMedium" }))
   {
       <div class="span12">
           <div>
               <div class="editor-field">
                   @Html.TextBox("txtDescription")
               </div>
           </div>

           <a href="javascript:$('#frmAddMedium').submit();", class="btn-primary btn-   small">Add Medium</a>
       </div>
   }


   <div id="MediumListDiv">
       @Html.Partial("Medium.List", Model)
   </div>
```

Comment: Please show the generated HTML page, not the ASP code.

Comment: I don't think you can just run jQuery like that without it being in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: please don't use inline javascript, it's really bad practice

Comment: Collin Henderson: Sure you can, if `$` is just defined when the link has been clicked. You shouldn't, though.

Comment: And quoting that comment from the other day: "Buttons perform an action. Links take people somewhere." Use a button eh? EDIT: oh bootstrap nevermind. :|

Comment: @quinnirill I'm guessing it wasn't though :-)

Comment: Check the error console. Remove the comma after your inline script.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the href attribute, use the onclick attribute.

```
    <a onclick="$('#frmAddMedium').submit();" class="btn-primary btn-small">Add Medium</a>
```